# The each block helper

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, handlebars.js

I´m having troubles using the each block helper with Handlerbars.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    </script>

    <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="entry">
            {{#each people}}
                <p>{{firstName}} &nbsp;{{lastName}}</p>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>


    <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var people = [
            {firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz"},
            {firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche"},
            {firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson"}
          ] 

          var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var html = template(people);
            $('#content').html(html);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

if I change the template to the code below, everything goes good:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        {{#.}}
            <p>{{firstName}} &nbsp;{{lastName}}</p>
        {{/.}}
    </div>
</script>
```

How to use the each helper block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.` or `this` with `{{#each}}`:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        {{#each .}}
            <p>{{firstName}} &nbsp;{{lastName}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

or:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        {{#each this}}
            <p>{{firstName}} &nbsp;{{lastName}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Demos:

- `.`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2Y4cF/
- `this`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8Pe2Z/ (thanks to [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348314/ben) for the reminder about this one)

The problem with `{{#each people}}` is that the template has no idea what name you've used for your JavaScript object. If you wanted to use `{{#each people}}` you'd have to add another layer:

```
var html = template({ people: people });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3tKET/

Comment: You can also use `{{#each this}}` which is maybe a little easier to read :]

Comment: @Ben: Good point, I've added that alternative for completeness.